# Script for q translate

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

Would like to add this script on my website just on the top of the memu right side, how can i do that?

Here's the code:

```
    <!-- GTranslate: https://gtranslate.io/ -->

<a href="https://jimbere.org" title="French" class="glink nturl notranslate" style="float:right;"><img src="//jimbere.org/wp-content/plugins/gtranslate/flags/24/fr.png" height="24" width="24" alt="French" /></a>
<a href="https://jimbere.org/test/news" title="English" class="glink nturl notranslate" style="float:right;margin-right:3px"><img src="//jimbere.org/test/wp-content/plugins/gtranslate/flags/24/en.png" height="24" width="24" alt="English"/></a>
<a href="https://jimbere.org/test/amayagwa" title="English" class="glink nturl notranslate" style="float:right;margin-right:3px"><img src="//jimbere.org/test/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/burundi-flag-icon-32.png " height="24" width="24" alt="Kirundi"/></a>


<a href="https://jimbere.org/amayagwa" title="English" class="glink nturl notranslate" style="float:right;margin-right:3px"><img src="//jimbere.org/test/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/burundi-flag-icon-32.png"  alt="Kirundi" / style=" position: absolute;
    width: 26px;height: 19px; margin-top: 2px;right:54px"></a>



<style type="text/css">
#goog-gt-tt {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-banner-frame {display:none !important;}
.goog-te-menu-value:hover {text-decoration:none !important;}
.goog-text-highlight {background-color:transparent !important;box-shadow:none !important;}
body {top:0 !important;}
#google_translate_element2 {display:none!important;}
</style>

<div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit2() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'fr',autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element2');}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function GTranslateGetCurrentLang() {var keyValue = document['cookie'].match('(^|;) ?googtrans=([^;]*)(;|$)');return keyValue ? keyValue[2].split('/')[2] : null;}
function GTranslateFireEvent(element,event){try{if(document.createEventObject){var evt=document.createEventObject();element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)}else{var evt=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');evt.initEvent(event,true,true);element.dispatchEvent(evt)}}catch(e){}}
function doGTranslate(lang_pair){if(lang_pair.value)lang_pair=lang_pair.value;if(lang_pair=='')return;var lang=lang_pair.split('|')[1];if(GTranslateGetCurrentLang() == null && lang == lang_pair.split('|')[0])return;var teCombo;var sel=document.getElementsByTagName('select');for(var i=0;i<sel.length;i++)if(/goog-te-combo/.test(sel[i].className)){teCombo=sel[i];break;}if(document.getElementById('google_translate_element2')==null||document.getElementById('google_translate_element2').innerHTML.length==0||teCombo.length==0||teCombo.innerHTML.length==0){setTimeout(function(){doGTranslate(lang_pair)},500)}else{teCombo.value=lang;GTranslateFireEvent(teCombo,'change');GTranslateFireEvent(teCombo,'change')}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check where wordpress are loading your menu or where is it the file header.php with your theme active and modify with your code because sometimes the menu are loaded at header.